# how we copy plist in NSDefault in ios 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

How do I copy the plist in nsdefault in iOS 5

Here is my code:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *myPlistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: 
                         [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@.plist", @"Bookmark"] ];


// If it's not there, copy it from the bundle
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ( ![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:myPlistPath] ) {
    NSString *pathToSettingsInBundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                        pathForResource:@"Bookmark" ofType:@"plist"];

    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:pathToSettingsInBundle toPath:myPlistPath error:&error];
}
[myPlistPath retain];
[myPlistPath release];
```

It runs in simulator correctly, but on the device it crashes.

Comment: Post the crash log and stack. What line does it crash on?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, NSDefault is not a thing, the code provided does not even use `NSUserDefaults` if thats what you meant,

Now the lines:

```
[myPlistPath retain];
[myPlistPath release];
```

are completely redundant, get rid of them.

Now use some common sense when debugging.

- cmd-shift-y bring up the console, see what it says.
- check that `Bookmark.plist` exists on the bundle, check if it exists in the documents directory.  Check both the simulator and the device.
- where does the execution crash?
- set some logs e.g. `if (error) NSLog(@"Error:%@",error);` Log the paths that are generated.
- does `if ( ![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:myPlistPath] )` evaluate to true or false. set up another log.
- profile the run using the zombies tool.

Do a bit more work first next time you are stuck.